# JBPM: Multiple transitions going out from a Task Node

Tags: java, jboss, workflow, jbpm, jboss-tools

in JBPM, can I have (technically) multiple transitions going out from a Task Node?

If Yes, is it a good practice?

Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but if you propagate execution of you process by callign token.signal() or taskInstance.end(), the transition choosen will be the first(in .xml file), no matter what conditions there will be on that transitions. If that condition evaluates to false exception will be thrown.

Out of the box only decision node supports choosing transition by evaluating conditions on them and the first transition with condition that evaluates to true will be choosen (or the first if no conditions evaluates to true).

But it is very simple to write custom actionhandler that propagates execution by hand (token.signal("transitionname")), and choosing the Right transition (tm).

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

Why not. You have two ways for a process and you can't define algorithmic way for choose one.

Answer (score 0):

I think what he wants is Fork,
Fork is a type of node that helps you with multiple transitions, more likely multi-flows, the best example this way is MC Donald's, if you are buying anything they're doing it in the same time you're paying, so when you finish the payment you have like a 'join' so it delivery and you can be happy or not.

If that's the point of question go to 'Fork' and 'Join' you can easily find answers in the JBPM Docs

Answer (score 0):

In the BPM there is a possibility. The task can have two or more transactions, and the user can choose one, two, or more transactions (or all transactions).

But I don't know how to implement this in jBPM...

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a fork node after task node.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple outgoing connections from a task node in jBPM, but in general I would recommend against this as a modeling best practice.  The reason is that by using multiple outgoing connections from one task node, you are hiding (in this case implicit) gateway behavior, making it not visible in the process.

Note that you have to set the jbpm.enable.multi.con property to true if you want to use multiple outgoing connections for tasks, otherwise the engine will mark it as invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
we can utilize the feature of FORK-JOIN which is provided by jbpm.
You can use this link https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v3/userguide/processmodelling.html